# Induced norm of a real matrix, symmetric, positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Describe geometrically $\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{A}=1\right\}$ where $\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert _{A}$ is the induced norm of a real matrix, symmetric, positive definite.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is symmetric, there exists an orthonormal basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ of eigenvectors of $A$. Write $Av_i = \lambda_i v_i$. Since $A$ is positive definite, $\lambda_i > 0$. Show that

$$ \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, | \, ||x||_A = 1 \} = \{ a_1 v_1 + \ldots + a_n v_n \, | \, \lambda_1 a_1^2 + \ldots + \lambda_n a_n^2 = 1 \} $$

which means that $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, | \, ||x||_A = 1 \}$ is an $n$-dimensional ellipsoid centered at the origin with axes $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ whose lengths are $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}}$.